# Application displays wrong hours and minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activeadmin

At first: thats not issue of wrong zone. In irb and database everything is fine. Problem occurs when I want to display dates (created_at, updated_at and all defined by myself in every model) in my views. I was trying to set time zone in application.rb and remove time formats from initializers and that didn't solved my issue.

**schema information generated by Annotate gem:**

```
#  created_at                      :datetime
#  updated_at                      :datetime
#  publish_at                      :datetime
```

**from irb:**

```
1.9.2-p290 :004 > Time.zone
 => (GMT+00:00) UTC 
1.9.2-p290 :005 > Time.zone.now
 => Fri, 24 Feb 2012 12:14:04 UTC +00:00 
1.9.2-p290 :006 > Time.now
 => 2012-02-24 13:14:07 +0100
```

**Examples:**

```
1.9.2-p290 :007 > Article.last
  Article Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` ORDER BY `articles`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<... created_at: "2012-02-24 12:04:24", updated_at: "2012-02-24 12:04:24", publish_at: "2012-02-24 12:04:24"...>
```

App displays:

Created_at  2012-02-24 12:02,
Updated_at  2012-02-24 12:02,
Publish_at  2012-02-24 12:02,

```
1.9.2-p290 :008 > Article.first
  Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` LIMIT 1
=> #<...created_at: "2012-01-30 10:28:07", updated_at: "2012-02-08 17:20:41", publish_at: "2012-02-08 17:20:33"...>
```

App displays:

Created_at  2012-01-30 10:01,
Updated_at  2012-02-08 17:02,
Publish_at  2012-02-08 17:02

this applies whole app (including active_admin)

Sorry for my English ;) Any ideas what is the reason of my problem?

Comment: Post your Update as an answer and accept it. It will help others that run into the same thing

Comment: That was silly mistake, but ok :)

Comment: Based on the people that up-voted your question it looks like many people found it useful regardless of sillyness :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it :) That was silly, but maybe someone will need reminder: App gets format from locale yml file first (thats only way to set date format in active admin; formats from initializers doesn't matter):

```
time:
  formats:
    default: "%Y-%m-%d"
    short: "%b %d"
    long: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%m"
```

and ofc minutes in long format should be %M (not %m)